# How to use boost bind with a member function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

The following code causes cl.exe to crash (MS VS2005).
I am trying to use boost bind to create a function to a calls a method of myclass:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <functional>

class myclass {
public:
    void fun1()       { printf("fun1()\n");      }
    void fun2(int i)  { printf("fun2(%d)\n", i); }

    void testit() {
        boost::function<void ()>    f1( boost::bind( &myclass::fun1, this ) );
        boost::function<void (int)> f2( boost::bind( &myclass::fun2, this ) ); //fails

        f1();
        f2(111);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    myclass mc;
    mc.testit();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
boost::function<void (int)> f2( boost::bind( &myclass::fun2, this, _1 ) );
```

This forwards the first parameter passed to the function object to the function using place-holders - you have to tell *Boost.Bind* how to handle the parameters. With your expression it would try to interpret it as a member function taking no arguments.
See e.g. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions) or [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers) for common usage patterns.

Note that VC8s cl.exe regularly crashes on *Boost.Bind* misuses - if in doubt use a test-case with gcc and you will probably get good hints like the template parameters *Bind*-internals were instantiated with if you read through the output.

Comment: any chance you can help out with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074756/how-to-avoid-static-member-function-when-using-gsl-with-c? it's similar but `std::function` gives an error

Comment: Thank you, this is sorta confusing but your answer saved my bacon!

Answer (score 3):

**Boost.Bind** is a library that simplifies and generalizes capabilities that originally required *std::bind1st()* and *std::bind2nd()*

Example 1.1: *std::for_each()* with a compatible function

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void print(int i)
{
  std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 2};
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print);
}
```

The third parameter of *std::for_each()* is a function or function object that expects a sole parameter. In *Example 1.1*, *std::for_each()* passes the numbers in the container v as sole parameters, one after another, to print().

If you need to pass in a function whose signature doesn’t meet the requirements of an algorithm, it gets more difficult. For example, if you want *print()* to accept an output stream as an additional parameter, you can no longer use it as is with *std::for_each()*.

Example 1.2. *std::for_each()* with *std::bind1st()*

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class print : public std::binary_function<std::ostream*, int, void>
{
public:
  void operator()(std::ostream *os, int i) const
  {
    *os << i << '\n';
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 2};
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind1st(print{}, &std::cout));
}
```

Like *Example 1.1*, *Example 1.2* writes all numbers in v to standard output. However, this time, the output stream is passed to print() as a parameter. To do this, the function *print()* is defined as a function object derived from *std::binary_function*.

With *Boost.Bind*, you don’t need to transform *print()* from a function to a function object. Instead, you use the function template *boost::bind()*, which is defined in *boost/bind.hpp*.

Example 1.3: *std::for_each()* with *boost::bind()*

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::ostream *os, int i)
{
  *os << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 2};
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(print, &std::cout, _1));
}
```

*Example 1.3* uses print() as a function, not as a function object. Because print() expects two parameters, the function can’t be passed directly to *std::for_each()*. Instead, *boost::bind()* is passed to *std::for_each()* and print() is passed as the first parameter to *boost::bind()*.

Since print() expects two parameters, those two parameters must also be passed to *boost::bind()*. They are a pointer to *std::cout* and *_1*.

*_1* is a placeholder. *Boost.Bin*d defines placeholders from *_1* to *_9*. These placeholders tell *boost::bind()* to return a function object that expects as many parameters as the placeholder with the greatest number. If, as in *Example 1.3*, only the placeholder *_1* is used, *boost::bind(*) returns a unary function object – a function object that expects a sole parameter. This is required in this case since *std::for_each()* passes only one parameter.

*std::for_each()* calls a unary function object. The value passed to the function object – a number from the container *v* – takes the position of the placeholder *_1*. *boost::bind()* takes the number and the pointer to std::cout and forwards them to print().

Please note that *boost::bind()*, like *std::bind1st()* and *std::bind2nd()*, takes parameters by value. To prevent the calling program from trying to copy *std::cout*, print() expects a pointer to a stream. Boost.Ref provides a function which allows you to pass a parameter by reference.

*Example 1.4* illustrates how to define a binary function object with *boost::bind()*. It uses the algorithm *std::sort()*, which expects a binary function as its third parameter.

*Example 1.4*. *std::sort()* with *boost::bind()*

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool compare(int i, int j)
{
  return i > j;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 2};
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(compare, _1, _2));
  for (int i : v)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

In *Example 1.4*, a binary function object is created because the placeholder *_2* is used. The algorithm *std::sort()* calls this binary function object with two values from the container v and evaluates the return value to sort the container. The function compare() is defined to sort *v* in descending order.

Since *compare()* is a binary function, it can be passed to *std::sort()* directly. However, it can still make sense to use *boost::bind()* because it lets you change the order of the parameters. For example, you can use *boost::bind()* if you want to sort the container in ascending order but don’t want to change compare()

*Example 1.5*. *std::sort()* with *boost::bind()* and changed order of placeholders

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool compare(int i, int j)
{
  return i > j;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 2};
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(compare, _2, _1));
  for (int i : v)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
class test_component
{
private:
    void on_wait_complete(const int i);
};

void test_component::on_wait_complete (const int i)
{
    cout << "on_wait_complete was called" << endl;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    // timerPtr_ is a variable declared in class test_component.
    timerPtr_->async_wait(boost::bind(&test_component::on_wait_complete, this, _1));
}
```