# How can I use std::thread inside a member function to call other member functions?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to call some of my member functions using threads. Suppose I have this

```
class myclass
{
public:
    myclass();
    double function1();
    void function2();
};

myclass::myclass()
{}


double myclass::function1()
{
    ...
    return a double;
}


void myclass::function2()
{
    //use a  thread to call function 1
    std::thread t(function1);//doesnt work!-wont compile
    std::thread t2(myclass::function1);//doesnt work either -wont compile
    std::thread t3(&myclass::function1);//doesnt work here either - wont compile
}
```

How can I call a member function by a thread inside another member function in C++? 
I am using Visual Studio 2013 Preview by the way.

**UPDATE 2:**

I did as i was told , some sections of code now compiles just fine and some others just don't!
this is the new sample code which generates the error :

```
class xGramManipulator
{
public:
    xGramManipulator();

    void ReadMonoGram();
    void ReadBiGram();

    void ReadMonoGram(double &);
    void ReadBiGram(double &);

    void CreateMonoGramAsync();
    void CreateBiGramAsync();
};

xGramManipulator::xGramManipulator()
{
}

void xGramManipulator::CreateMonoGramAsync()
{
    thread t(&xGramManipulator::ReadMonoGram, this);
}

void xGramManipulator::CreateBiGramAsync()
{
    thread t = thread(&xGramManipulator::ReadBiGram, this);
}
```

The above code(those two Async member functions) generates the following errors :
Error Message:

> error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Comment: What prevented you from formatting your question? You've been an active SO member for almost two years. Also, "doesnt work!" is hardly a useful description of your technical problem. Please do better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The reason is simple ,I just accidentally hit Enter and the question was submitted, before i even try to format it.Though secods after submission it was kindly formatted by 
"R. Martinho Fernandes ".

Comment: Okay, that's a good reason. Thanks.

Comment: The edited code example compiles fine for me. Make sure you `#include <thread>` and use `std::thread`, though. Also, please don't overwrite your original question and change it. You can *append* to it, but now you've made all the answers nonsensical.

Comment: Ok, its included! then why doest it not compile in Visual Studio 2013 preview?
Where did you compile it?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The question is now updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say `std::thread(&myclass::function1, this)`.

If you need to disambiguate overloads, you have to cast the function pointer explicitly:

```
std::thread(static_cast<void (xGramManipulator::*)()>(&xGramManipulator::ReadMonoGram), this)
```

Comment: Please stop answering blatant dupes! OMG!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Whoops, sorry. Next time!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I was young and needed the rep... And I'm not always sober enough to know whether there are dupes :-S I usually only spot dupes in particular areas I feel stronly about, like `eof()`, where the answer is much longer to type out than it takes to close.

Comment: @KerrekSB Nevermind, there isn't anything wrong with answering a question anyway. It's not your fault if it turns out to be a duplicate (and an answer doesn't ever hurt anybody).

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB :) i was going to format the code but suddenly i hit enter and it got posted , thanks for formatting and also for the answer ;)

Comment: by the way is this wrong?
thread t(&xGramManipulator::ReadMonoGram, this);
because i get compilation error saying :
"error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments"

Comment: @Hossein: You have to bind *all* the arguments. Non-static member functions take one instance argument plus explicit arguments, but you have to provide all the other arguments as well.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, an answer can hurt the community, just in the same way that giving someone money can hurt them (if it prevents them from bothering to get their own job). Responsible community members shall not encourage dupes and [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) questions by answering them!

Comment: @kerrekSB:I know that , the problem is that that function takes no argument at all!

Comment: @Hossein: Please post representative code for your actual problem...

Comment: @Hossein: Well, my comments apply exactly. You need to specify *all* the arguments, like `std::thread t(&xGramManipulator::ReadMonoGram, this, 0.5);`.

Comment: I dont want to use the parametrized overload here, I want to run the parameterless version in my thread!

Comment: @Hossein: Right, I got it - if you have multiple overloads, you have to disambiguate the function pointer explicitly. I added that.

Comment: Thanks, But whats that crazy syntax? would you add abit more explanation to your answer so that i can understand whats going on?

Comment: @Hossein: It's just a cast to the type of the function you want. Look up member function types for details. The type of the other overload is `void (xGramManipulator::*)(double)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using boost::bind as described here to bind the implicit "this" parameter of a member function:

[How to use boost bind with a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function)

This will make it a function without parameters and you can use it to start a thread.

Comment: Kerrek SB's answer is better since it is easier.

Comment: It's also an actual answer, rather than a hyperlink.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"It's also an actual answer, rather than a hyperlink."* - Yet doesn't really explain anything either but just provides the *"working"* code.

Comment: There is no need to use `boost::bind` or `std::bind`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: You're right.

Comment: @juanchopanza: that's why I commented to upvote Kerrek SBs answer.