# How would I use the same instance of a class created in main in another class's function?

Tags: c++

How would I use the same instance of a class created in main in another class's function?

For example in main I have the code below. A `SignatureBlock` object is created at the beginning and its `toString()` function is used shortly after. Later in the code, a `Game` object is created and its `playGame()` function is called. My problem is that the `playGame()` function also needs to use `SignatureBlock`'s `toString()` function.

It seems to me I only have two choices. Either create a new `SignatureBlock` object in the `Game` class and then use the new object's `toString()` function, or pass the `SignatureBlock` object created in main to the `playGame` function.

I don't really like either of these solution and I was wondering if someone had a better way of doing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include "SignatureBlock.h"

int main() 
{
    SignatureBlock myBlock;
    bool done = false;
    do
    {
        std::cout << myBlock.toString();

        std::cout <<    "************\n" 
                        "Tic Tac Toe!\n"
                        "************\n";
        std::cout <<    "1. Play game!\n"
                        "2. exit\n"
                        "\nEnter 1 or 2: ";
        std::string option;
        std::getline(std::cin,option);
        if (option == "1")
        {       
            Game myGame;
            myGame.playGame();
        }
        else if (option == "2")
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid input";
        }
    }
    while (!done);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you like passing the class through? If you pass it as a pointer, then you're not copying data, but it gives your class access to the running instance of SignatureBlock.

Comment: @DylanLawrence: Objects are *data*, not *code*, so an object cannot "run".

Comment: If you don't like passing myBlock, you can pass the return value of myBlock.toString() since this is what you require in playgame() function.

Comment: you can declare the SignatureBlock global instead of local in your main. Generally, in practice, it's not a good idea - but it may help you in this particular case.  Personally I'd pass the instance of the class through a pointer to the function where it's needed

Comment: You could (eugh....) make the instance of SignatureBlock global.

Answer (score 2):

Other options -

1. Pass a pointer to the toString() method. This is a bit problematic in C++ for several reasons. C++ distinguishes between static and member functions, member function signatures also depend on the class and so on. In addition - invoking a member function (which is what you need) requires a reference to the object. To overcome this you can you use [boost's function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/function.html) and [boost bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html), see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function).
2. You can declare your SignatureBlock as a global variable so it'll be accessible to any Game object. This is an option, but it's VERY not recommended for various reasons.

I still think passing a pointer or a reference to the SignatureBlock constructor is the best option. If you really want to hide implementation details, have Game expect an "interface" (a pure virtual class) that declares a toString() method and have SignatureBlock inherit from it.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll just go with the pointer. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @navig8tr The only reason to prefer a pointer over a reference is if you want to allow for passing a "null". It doesn't look like you need this functionality, so a reference would be a better option.

Comment: Okay I'm passing by reference like this: `void playGame(const SignatureBlock &myBlock);`

Comment: @navig8tr - if you pass it as const, make sure toString() is marked as const as well (and that it is indeed a function that does not change the state of the object)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be by making `toString()` a `static` function. This is good if `toString()` is used only to run some logic rather than store data in an object and do operations on it. From your use case I believe making `toString()` `static` would be the perfect option.

For using static functions you dont need to create any object. Use following line wherever you want to call this function.

```
SignatureBlock::toString();
```

Comment: I thought the same, but usually `toString()` functions are used to write some "instance-specific" data of the object, so making it static would not do the deal, since you don't have access to the object specific data anymore.

Comment: From the use case and the question it does not appear to me that toString() requires class variables. What it does and how it does can only be answered by OP.

Comment: I agree in so far, that the OP just uses `std::cout << myBlock.toString();` without having any specific data in `myBlock`. So yeah, telling from the code he provided it seems it has no object-specific data.

Comment: The `toString` does use data in the object.

Comment: `toString` combines several string fields (instantiated by a no-arg constructor) and returns them as a single string.