# binding to boost::function class member compilation error

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

```
boost::function<void()> test_func;

struct test_t
{
   boost::function<void(int)> foo_;

   void test()
   {
      // This works as expected
      test_func = boost::bind(test_t::foo_, 1);
   }

};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
      test_t test;

      test.test();

      // error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'test_t::foo_'
      test_func = boost::bind(test_t::foo_, &test, 1);

      const auto a = 0;

   return 0;
}
```

What the problem with the code? Why code test_func = boost::bind(test_t::foo_, &test, 1); compiles in test_t::test() and gives me the error in main()?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because inside a method `test_t::foo_` refers to `this->foo_`, while `test_t::foo_` in `main` could refer to `foo_` only if it was a static member of that class. You need to write `test.foo_` there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more or less what the error says. `test_t::foo_` is not a function; it's a functor (function object), and it's not static. As such, you cannot access it without a `test_t` object. Try this:

`test_func = boost::bind(test.foo_, 1);`