# Accept any function (but only functions) as a parameter

Tags: c++

Is there a way to accept any function signature as a parameter? For example:

```
void accepter(void (*func)(int)) {  ... }
```

would accept anything of type `void (*)(int)`. I know I could use a template, such as:

```
template<class T>
void accepter(T func) { ... }
```

which would work, but then it allows non-functions to be passed in. How do I filter only for functions in the same way that a `void *` filters for any type of pointer?

Comment: If you try to call it, you will get a compile-time error. What are you doing that you are getting a link-time error? The only way I see would be if you're explicitly instantiating the template only for function types, but you don't seem to be doing that...

Comment: Taking the address of the function (jit compiler)

Comment: That still won't cause a link-time error.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's true. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Use C++11 std::function or boost::function, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using C++11's `std::function` should work:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void test (std::function<T> func) {
```

You can use this, e.g.:

```
int foo (int);
std::sting bar (bool);

test(std::function<int(int)>(foo));
test(std::function<std::string(bool)>(bar));
```

Comment: Shame there's no implicit conversion for `std::function`. This works though!