# Why boost::bind incompatible with forward declaration?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

`boost::bind` is unable to bind parameters declared via a forward declaration.

Can anyone explain why? Is this a boost bug?

Sample code:

```
#include "boost/function.hpp" 
#include "boost/bind.hpp" 
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class B;
class A
{
public:
    A() {}

    void func1(int i)                      { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << i << ")\n"; } 
    void func2(const std::string& s)       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << s << ")\n"; }
    void func3(const B& b)       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << "unknown" << ")\n"; } 

    static void dispatch(      std::vector<A>& vect, boost::function<void(A      &)> const& func)
    {
        for ( std::vector<A>::iterator iter = vect.begin();
              iter != vect.end();
              ++iter )
        {
            func(*iter);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vect(3);

    A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func1, _1, 3));
    A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func2, _1, "hello"));

    const B* b = NULL;
    A a;
    a.func3( *b ); // compiles and works!!
    A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func3, _1, *b)); // does not compile!!
}
```

Error reported is:

```
main.cpp:37:52: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'
     A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func3, _1, *b)); // does not compile
```

Live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f9437627fdf3c53

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because bind stores the bound parameters *by value*.

If you do not want that, wrap them in reference wrappers: `boost::ref(x)` or `boost::cref(x)`.

```
A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func3, _1, boost::cref(*b)));
```

Compiles:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b8e68a1e08144f)</kbd>**

```
#include "boost/function.hpp" 
#include "boost/bind.hpp" 
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class B;
class A
{
public:
    A() {}

    void func1(int i)                      { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << i << ")\n"; } 
    void func2(const std::string& s)       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << s << ")\n"; }
    void func3(const B& b)       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << "unknown" << ")\n"; } 

    static void dispatch(      std::vector<A>& vect, boost::function<void(A      &)> const& func)
    {
        for ( std::vector<A>::iterator iter = vect.begin();
              iter != vect.end();
              ++iter )
        {
            func(*iter);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vect(3);

    A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func1, _1, 3));
    A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func2, _1, "hello"));

    const B* b = NULL;
    A a;
    a.func3( *b ); // compiles and works!!
    A::dispatch(vect, boost::bind(&A::func3, _1, boost::cref(*b))); 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that without `boost::cref` a copy is done when I was actually expeting no copy to be done?

Comment: Can't speak for your expectations, but yes, this is exactly what I said in the first sentence :)

Comment: Can't this be risky in some situations?

Comment: Yes, it can't. It's never risky to copy. It's far more risky to hold a reference (copies don't have lifetime issues, i.e. they don't become dangling). Welcome to C++, the language of _value-semantics-by-default_

Comment: `never risky to copy` as far as you respected the rule of three...which may not be the case when you pass references everywhere in your code!

Comment: If you don't respect [Rule Of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) you deserve what's coming :) (It's **easy** to prevent copying)

Comment: Got it ;-). Thanks again for your help